# Difference between "socket" and "outlet"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

While translating a technical document I began thinking about *socket* and *outlet*. It seems like they're mostly interchangeable. Is that correct? Or is there a difference between the two?

Comment: please accept the right answer!

Answer (score 23):

The other answers are being too specific.  A ***socket*** is something into which something is *plugged* or *fitted* (also called a ***receptacle***).  An ***outlet*** is something that something comes ***out*** of.

A ***light socket*** is called a light ***socket*** because a light bulb is inserted into it.
A ***power outlet*** is called an ***outlet*** because power comes *out* of it.  It could conceivably be called a ***power socket*** but this is not usual and is possibly confusing.

Neither of these examples is intended to imply the power doesn't come out of a light ***socket*** or that a plug isn't plugged into a power ***outlet***.   Those are facts but not related to the terms in question themselves.

If you are in any doubt that context is not enough, just use ***light socket*** and ***power outlet***.

---

I want to add one more comment, eight years later.   It's also not usual to call the thing that's installed in your wall a ***receptacle***.  In this context, usually the speaker is referring the literal piece of equipment installed there that *receives* the plug.   In other words, you're mostly talking about what the form of the thing is (a hole for a plug) and not what it does (outputs power).

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer; There are outlets that are not sockets (There's several from the local sewer) and sockets that aren't outlets (particularly if you like putting together cheap furniture).

Comment: Good answer, although I'd use "fitted", not "plugged" to describe the general meaning of "socket" - for example, an eye fits into an eye socket, but I wouldn't describe it as "plugged in".

Comment: @ Ziv, if we ever see you again, perhaps you'd like to accept this answer?

Comment: In your edit, did you mean 'receptable' or 'receptacle'?

Comment: Actually (at least in the US) the term "outlet", "socket", and "receptacle" are all distinct and have a specific meaning in the electrical trade. An "outlet" is the location that can have one or more power jacks. Each individual jack is a "receptacle". A "socket" is actually where a device is inserted: usually a light bulb (but it can be a microchip or some other device, on circuit boards.)

Answer (score 12):

In British English, 'socket' is the word that normally describes the place in the wall where you put a plug to connect to the electricity supply. 'Outlet' might conceivably be used in some technical contexts, but it has other meanings too and could be ambiguous.

Comment: In American English, both 'outlet' and 'socket' are used to describe this. I believe the usual adjectives for these words are 'electrical outlet' and 'wall socket'. For other uses of these words, they are usually **not** interchangeable.

Comment: If you are referring to an electrical power receptacle, at least in the US, socket and outlet both apply, they just refer to different aspects or characteristics.  It is a socket in the sense that it is the receptacle into which you insert a plug.  It is an outlet in the sense that electricity comes out.  Some people call it a "wall socket", some call it a "wall outlet" or "power outlet".  Outlet is probably used more frequently.

Answer (score 9):

In American English and when speaking about electrical circuits and devices, a "socket" is something into which a light bulb is screwed, while an "outlet" is something into which electrical cords are plugged.

Light socket: [image]  Electrical outlet: [image]

Comment: Further to other comments relating to BrE terms for these things the fitting into which a bulb is fitted is called a "bulb holder" in BrE and the term "light socket" doesn't exist in normal usage.

Comment: To add to this: each of the individual jacks on that outlet are "receptacles." The term "outlet" is the combined unit that has two (or more) receptacles on it.

Answer (score 6):

This really does depend on your dialect. This is the first time I have seen this meaning of *outlet*. I've never heard it before. So if you're writing for a British or Irish audience, *socket* is your only option.

Comment: For BrE or IrE, is that because 'outlet' doesn't mean anything at all or because it means something else entirely?

Comment: @Mitch. It is used, as a general word meaning "somewhere something comes out of". I'd understand *power outlet*, but I'd expect it to refer to some unusual power outlet, such as those used on building sites. Using that phrase to refer to a normal socket would seem quite odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the endpoint of a logical network connection (such as [Berkeley sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets)), only the term 'socket' is used. These are never called 'outlets'. Only physical endpoints are ever called 'outlets'.

Answer (score 1):

The official designation in Australia used to be "General Purpose Outlet" (GPO).  However, the official designation is NOW "Socket Outlet".