# Socket or outlet, which one do you use when explaining to a child?

Tags: word-usage, differences, american-english, australian-english, canadian-english

I'm just curious....

In the USA, how do you explain to a child 'don't put anything in the electrical outlet' or 'don't play with a wall socket'??

How do you say the same thing around the globe?

Comment: [This issue has bee previously raised at ELU check this link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42259/difference-between-socket-and-outlet)

Comment: [And this Ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=electrical+socket%2Celectrical+outlet&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Celectrical%20socket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Celectrical%20outlet%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: One of your tags is American-English, in the US 'outlet' is more frequently used according to the Ngram query linked. That said, because your teaching a child you might go with 'socket' and create a rhyming phrase '**if you stick it in the socket, it will shock it!**, as children (and adults) often memorize rhymed phrases more easily.

Comment: I would say socket, except that we call them *power points*. Perhaps that's changed. My adult children perhaps call them sockets.

Answer (score 1):

I find both acceptable.

Personally, I would be more likely to say "socket" or "wall socket" in the context of a kid playing with it (when the emphasis is on its physical reality), and "outlet" or "electrical outlet" in the context of my wanting to plug something into it (when the emphasis is on its intended function); but I really wouldn't bat an eye if someone else had the exact opposite preference.

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. We call it wall socket here in the UK.