# "receptacle" vs. "outlet" in AmEng

Tags: differences, american-english, word-usage, dialects

What's the difference between ***receptacle*** and ***outlet*** to cal the device in a wall you put a plug into in order to provide electricity for a lamp, television, etc.?

> - **outlet**
>
> (also *receptacle*, *socket*) (both North American English) (British English *power point*) a device in a wall that you put a plug into in order to connect electrical equipment to the power supply of a building
>
> [OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/receptacle?q=receptacle)
>
> *US* : a device in a wall into which an electric cord can be plugged in order to provide electricity for a lamp, television, etc.
>
> *electrical outlets*; *a wall outlet*
>
> — called also *socket*, (*British*) *point*, (*British*) *power point*
>
> [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/outlet)
>
> - **receptacle**
>
> *US* : a device into which an electric cord can be plugged in order to provide electricity for a lamp, television, etc.
>   an electrical receptacle [=outlet]
>
> [MWLD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/receptacle)

Comment: Please read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets , particularly the "Concepts and terminology" section, and see if it answers your question

Comment: Related: *[Difference between “socket” and “outlet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42259)*

Comment: @MaxWilliams Thanks Max. It helped some. Sounds like both terms can be used just about interchangeably...

Comment: Nowadays, nothing. The terms come from inventions, patents, and marketing  during the earliest days of home electrification. Receptacle seems to have come from Chapman. The earliest wall sockets were lamp sockets mounted in a wall. Appliances of the time had screw bases identical to bulbs. These wall sockets were a hazard to curious children, so specific adapters were built to screw into wall sockets and prevent electrical shocks. Eventually, companies such as Chapman began making wall receptacles that weren't light sockets. lots of info and examples here - http://www.rexophone.com/?p=1175

Comment: Outlet became a generic term for the multitude of incompatible wall recepticals, ceiling fixtures, and sconces in a house. Realtors would describe these outlets in great detail in their listings.

Comment: The main thing is that "receptacle" is the term used in the National Electrical Code and other "official" documents.

Comment: Speaking as a mid-western America and FWIW, a receptacle is that part of a lamp into which you screw the lightbulb.  I've rarely (if ever) heard it used in place of outlet.

Comment: @cobaltduck -- All I've ever heard (here in the US Midwest) for the place you put a light bulb is "socket".  "Screw the light bulb into the socket."

Comment: A luminaire isn't a lamp until you put a bulb in its socket. I'm also Midwestern and *never* heard a lamp fixture's socket referred to as a receptacle. Only burnt-out bulbs go in *the receptacle* (the garbage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NEC 2008**

Outlet:

> A point on the wiring system at which current is taken to supply utilization equipment.

Receptacle:

> A receptacle is a contact device installed at the outlet for the connection of an attachment plug. A single receptacle is a single contact device with no other contact device on the same yoke.

–[flashcardmachine.com](http://www.flashcardmachine.com/nec-2008-definitions.html)

An *outlet* is a location. A *receptacle* is an object.